# questions on address after disassembler

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m, bare-metal, thumb

I'm new to gnu asm with arm and confused by some code. I wrote a code like this:

```
.code 16

.text

vectors:

    .word STACKINIT
    .word _start + 1
    ..... (defines vectors)

_start:

    mov r0, #0xAB
    .... (other code)
```

after disassembly with arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objdump, I got these code as:

```
00008060 <vectors>:

    8060:   20005000    .word   0x20005000
    8064:   000080d1    .word   0x000080d1
    8068:   000080f9    .word   0x000080f9
  ........

000080d0 <_start>:

    80d0:   20ab        movs    r0, #171    ; 0xab
```

what confused me is the address. Why for vectors the start address is 00008060, not the 0x0000 and why the start address for _start is 000080d0, not 0x00d0? Thanks.

Comment: 1) you have not provided enough info. 2) _start+1 is not a good habit use .thumb_func it is address ORRed with 1 not PLUS one, you will get into trouble with that some day if the tools produce the correct address. 3) yes your vector table is messed up...

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided enough info.  Using plus one instead of or one is bad because when you get a correct address it will then get modified by the plus one and be wrong.  You should never need to do the plus one anyway.  Here is a very simple working example and you can fill the gap between what you have and this.

so.s

```
.thumb
.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
stacktop: .word 0x20001000
.word reset
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang

.thumb_func
reset:
    @bl notmain
    b hang

.thumb_func
hang:   b .
```

so.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

build

```
arm-none-eabi-as so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -o so.elf -T so.ld so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.elf > so.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy so.elf so.bin -O binary
```

arm-whatever-linux-whatever would have worked too...

```
00000000 <_start>:
   0:   20001000
   4:   00000041
   8:   00000043
   c:   00000043
  10:   00000043
  14:   00000043
  18:   00000043
  1c:   00000043
  20:   00000043
  24:   00000043
  28:   00000043
  2c:   00000043
  30:   00000043
  34:   00000043
  38:   00000043
  3c:   00000043

00000040 <reset>:
  40:   e7ff        b.n 42 <hang>

00000042 <hang>:
  42:   e7fe        b.n 42 <hang>
```

Moving _start to the front is not what made it line up with zero, having so.o first on the ld command line is what did that, since there are no other objects it is the only on the command line, but if the linker script does not call out a specific file name then it falls to the command line ordering.  For this kind of work you dont care about where _start is you care about where the vector table is.  The entry point is defined by silicon you are not loading these programs from an operating system which uses _start as the entry point.

.thumb_func is the cheapest way to tell the assembler that the next label is a function (and thus the address of is orred with 1), there is more detailed syntax you can use to declare a procedure or function, examine the assembly output of a C compiled function to see this more detailed way to do it and choose your favorite.

.thumb vs .code 16 should be interchangeable.  Eventually if using a cortex-m3 or m4 or (larger number, something other than a cortex-m0 or m1) you will want to specify that

```
.cpu cortex-m3
```

or

```
-mcpu=cortex-m3
```

on the gas and gcc command lines.

It appears either your linker script moved _start or you have other stuff in your binary you didnt show us or you might have multiple files to create what you showed us, dont know you didnt provide enough information.  We should be able to take what you provided and be able to repeat it...

EDIT

for one particular brand that uses cortex-m chips the user flash is actually at 0x08000000, they map it to 0x00000000 when you boot in that mode.  The window is I dont know how large, so you can build it for 0x00000000 or 0x08000000 for the .text address space, this shows how changing the linker script changes the output.

flash.s

```
.thumb

.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
stacktop: .word 0x20001000
.word reset
.word hang @ NMI
.word hang @ HardFault
.word hang @ MemManage
.word hang @ BusFault
.word hang @ UsageFault
.word hang @ 7
.word hang @ 8
.word hang @ 9
.word hang @ 10
.word hang @ SVCall
.word hang @ DebugMonitor
.word hang @ Reserved
.word hang @ PendSV
.word hang @ SysTick
.word hang @ External interrupt 0
.word hang @ External interrupt 1
.word hang @ External interrupt 2

.thumb_func
reset:
    bl notmain
    b hang

.thumb_func
hang:   b .

.thumb_func
.globl dummy
dummy:
    bx lr
```

notmain.c

```
extern void dummy ( unsigned int );
void notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    for(ra=0;ra<100;ra++) dummy(ra);
}
```

flash.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

build

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding  -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -c notmain.c -o notmain.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -o notmain.elf -T flash.ld flash.o notmain.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D notmain.elf > notmain.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy notmain.elf notmain.bin -O binary
```

plus it includes some C code linked in.

because flash.o was before notmain.o on the linker command line it goes first into .text (with a linker script this generic).

```
08000000 <_start>:
 8000000:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
 8000004:   0800004d    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r3, r6}
 8000008:   08000053    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r4, r6}
 800000c:   08000053    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r4, r6}
 8000010:   08000053    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r4, r6}
 8000014:   08000053    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r4, r6}
 8000018:   08000053    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r4, r6}
 800001c:   08000053    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r4, r6}
 8000020:   08000053    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r4, r6}
 8000024:   08000053    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r4, r6}
 8000028:   08000053    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r4, r6}
```

note that .text now starts at 0x08000000 per the linker script.  This is fine because it will get mapped to 0x00000000 by this hardware which will read the value at address 0x00000004 which is 0x0800004d and branch to 0x0800004c

```
0800004c <reset>:
 800004c:   f000 f804   bl  8000058 <notmain>
 8000050:   e7ff        b.n 8000052 <hang>

08000052 <hang>:
 8000052:   e7fe        b.n 8000052 <hang>

08000054 <dummy>:
 8000054:   4770        bx  lr
    ...

08000058 <notmain>:
 8000058:   b510        push    {r4, lr}
 800005a:   2400        movs    r4, #0
 800005c:   1c20        adds    r0, r4, #0
 800005e:   3401        adds    r4, #1
 8000060:   f7ff fff8   bl  8000054 <dummy>
 8000064:   2c64        cmp r4, #100    ; 0x64
 8000066:   d1f9        bne.n   800005c <notmain+0x4>
 8000068:   bd10        pop {r4, pc}
 800006a:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
```

Now if you remove the .thumb_func in front of hang and dummy then with dummy we get lucky it works out

8000060:   f7ff fff8   bl  8000054

because a branch link was used it was assumed to be in the same mode, but the one in front of hang makes the vector table wrong

```
08000000 <_start>:
 8000000:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
 8000004:   0800004d    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r3, r6}
 8000008:   08000052    stmdaeq r0, {r1, r4, r6}
 800000c:   08000052    stmdaeq r0, {r1, r4, r6}
 8000010:   08000052    stmdaeq r0, {r1, r4, r6}
```

Using -c on the gcc command line and linking myself with my own linker script and/or using the -Xlinker gcc option to feed the linker the linker script (and being careful of ordering of files on the gcc command line) you can control the linker script which you have to do here since you appear to me to be aiming at a cortex-m processor not writing an arm linux  application.  the compiler and assembler can be treated generically but you want to avoid the default bootstrap (crt0.o in the gnu world) and linker script, unless you have a gnu build targeted directly at your specific platform (the default is for your platform).  Which you can do when you build your C library if you want, if you use a C library.  With bare metal you dont have a system to make calls to so much of the C library falls apart.

Comment: actually seeing that you used arm-none-linux-gnueabi you probably didnt make your own linker script so the default 0x8000 start address was used then you had your vectors so _start was somewhere off the end of that, so this all makes perfect sense.  but wont work, you need to use your own linker script, repeat your experiement with your code but use my linker script or make your own, replace arm-none-eabi with arm-linux-gnueabi and use the same commands, your assembly language my linker script.

Comment: Hi, i'm very appreciate your reply. I'm studying what you have posted and may need more time to understand it. But I guest the so.ld may be a tip. I didn't create this file. Could you please tell me what is its function? thanks

Comment: in this case it is the "linker script" for the linker.  There is typically a default one, no doubt with arm-linux-whatever there is a linker script that creates applications that run on arm linux meaning the entry point is at 0x8000 or 0x80000, there is a default linker script somewhere.  When you call gcc it calls the assembler after compiling then the linker unless you tell it not to.

Comment: If you change the address 0x00000000 to say 0x00003000 in the rom origin line then the vector table in this case the beginning of text will be at 0x3000 not 0x0000 like we want.

Comment: Likewise if I had some global variables, they would have been allocated at compile/link time to start at address 0x20000000 (.data basically) because the linker script tells the linker to do that.  you can do without a linker script and pass -Ttext=0x00000000 -Tdata=0x20000000 to the linker, but I have found some warts with doing that that you dont get with the linker script.  Most linker scripts you find will be much more compilicated for reasons desired by that programmer, I have little to no need for any of that.

Comment: Thank you. There are too much information now. I need to learn them carefully. Thanks very much